# JavaScript exception but only with breakpoint active while stepping thru code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm having a strange issue with some old JS code in an ASP.NET web application (circa 2006-2008 code base and updated to .NET 4.8).  I deployed to a test server where the web app will not populate a dropdown control.  Our production version does populate the dropdown correctly.  The code is identical between the two servers (test and production) so it must be some environmental settings or IIS setting or maybe even a .NET 4.8 configuration.

On my development PC (local running IIS Express), if I do **NOT** place a breakpoint the code works as it should and the dropdown is populated correctly.

I've checked the web.config to make sure all is good for each environment, everything appears to be set correctly.

I've looked at IIS on both test and production servers and I don't see anything different.

I tried remote debugging on the test server but that didn't reveal anything different than running debug on local source.

When debugging with my local dev PC where I step thru the code I get an exception in the JS code (be aware the is JS in ASP.NET app so Visual Studio uses [Dynamic] in the tab).  I'm not going to go into details of why JS code is being used when ASP.NET code behind could accomplish the same functionality more cleanly, but it's an old web app and clearly had many developer footprints where some seemed to be more JS developers while others more ASP.NET developers.  Some of the code is really old and really bad, loading ActiveX controls on the fly etc.

That suggests to me that this might be some type of event timing issue.  Unfortunately the exception provides no specific details on what the error is.

Any thoughts on how to proceed or get a more meaningful exception message out of the JS code?

Comment: Breakpoints causing issues like this in javascript (or fixing them) are almost always going to be a case of a race condition. Look for things like setting variables within the callback of an XHR call and then accessing those variables in incorrect ways.

Comment: @KevinB It's starting to feel like a .NET 4.6 vs. 4.8 issue or like you said accessing to early ... that's the only difference between the two environments ... really old coding methods using ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"), POST, send ... no awaits here ... not sure if it's a race condition, but most likely callback not happening fast enough (by chance slow debug vs. deployed execution).

Comment: This definitely does seem to be an XHR/synchronous issue per xmlHTTP.open ("POST", sURL, false) where false indicates wait for send() to complete ... does IIS8.5 treat this differently than IIS 10.x?  Any JQuery.ajax coders that might have alternate solution?

Comment: Yes, at a certain point browsers stopped obeying the third parameter... and there's no way around it other than coding with that fact in mind, ;) that may turn out to be quite challenging, depending on how much code depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting console log statements into the JavaScript code and running the code on the test server.

```
console.log("Site has loaded");
var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
console.log(value);
```

Then read the logs and errors from the debug browser's *Developer Tools* (press <kbd>F12</kbd> and select the *Console* tab).
[Chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO36t.png)

Some things to try:

- Double check the system references and their version numbers that they are the same.
- Check firewall settings that they are not blocking the loading of a web reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and report back.  If I can't make the JS work, I'll probably just convert the JS into APS.NET code behind.  On a side note, I have to run this app in IE compatibility mode (it's that old) and it will not run under Chrome (unfortunately).

Comment: FYI, no console.log support in IE for what I'm doing with this ancient code (over 17 years old).  Definitely seems to be an XHR issue (synchronous).